# highlight some texts in <summary> inline C# code doc in VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I would like to change font to bold for some text in C# inline code documentation summary in VS2013 on win 7.

```
   /// <summary>
   /// my text , the input args in the order of <b>"myname", "address"</b> 
   /// </summary>
   /// <paramref name="myname"/>
   /// <paramref  name="address"/>
   /// <returns></returns>
```

the link cannot help me
    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11082/C-and-XML-Source-Code-Documentation

I also need to highlight some words in the  inline code doc when a parameter is typed.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no bold tag in the XML within the C# IDE of VS. The argument list and order are self-documented by the function definition.

For the current list of valid tags, see:

[Microsoft's recommended tags for documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax(v=vs.140).aspx)